# Capture result from a function in C (cmd1 | cmd2)

Tags: c

Let us say that cmd1 print something on stdout. How can I capture it with cmd1 in C such that cmd1 | cmd2 works.

i.e

```
cmd1{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello");
    }

cmd2 : should take "hello" and only print "hel".
```

Comment: Are cmd1 and cmd2 functions in the same program, or are they command lines programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable pipeline operation, cmd2 should read from `stdin`.

For example, since `fgets()` reads from `stdin`, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        printf("%.*s\n", 3, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the output is on multiple lines, so: line1: hello, line2:hello, line3:hello. And I want to print only the first two lines but both being "hel"

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Does my answer satisfy *this* question?

Answer (score 0):

How stdout interacts with another program has nothing to do with C -- this is the operating system.  However, on every OS I've used typing

```
 cmd1 | cmd2
```

Will send the stdout of cmd1 to the stdin of cmd2.

If this is not working then maybe you have to flush the buffer in your cmd1 program.  (This depends on many things... but try it.)